# Asking a question defaults to my first pinned site

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When I am on a Stack Exchange site, e.g. Meta Stack Exchange, and press the ask a question button, it will default to that site (Meta Stack Exchange) in the new question. If I press the button to show reputation change messages, then click on the button to ask a question, the default is the first pinned site on my 'Your Sites' list, but it used to be the same as what I am currently viewing (MSE, in this example).

App version: 1.0.52

Comment: There isn't a drop-down menu to select the site you want to ask a question?

Comment: There is but normally it defaults to whichever site you are on.

Comment: I didn't notice that regression. I experience the same on my phone, but on the tablet they have changed how the reputation button works (grays out the background and brings a smaller window into the foreground), so it isn't really relevant there. Perhaps in adding the new feature that was somehow changed.

Comment: I have suggested an edit to clarify that the bug does not default to Stack Overflow. It defaults to the first pinned site.

Comment: Damn this is an awesome catch. You can tell it's causing issues since clicking the "Achievements" button also changes from the specific site's icon on the action bar to the generic SE icon.

Answer (score 1):

This was **such** a fun bug. It's fixed as of the next beta update so anything version 1.0.53 and above.

What was happening here is that most of our views (Activities / Fragments) have the concept of current site, and when the "Ask Question" page was opening it checked if the last view was site specific, and if it was got the site value from it. Since the achievements view is a global one, the page was finding nothing for the current site and using the default.

The achievements page is no longer considered a first-class view on phones (it never was on tablets since it's a real pop-up there, not a slide-in page takeover) and all of the logic for get-current-site now works via the view behind it, rather than checking against the achievements page itself. This also has the nice benefit of not getting rid of the site's logo in the action bar when you're viewing a question or something and decide to check your reputation changes.